# Phrasing a job description

Tags: software-industry, resume, career-development

I have quick question maybe I am overthinking it but would like to consult how to describe the job responsibilities I have in one sentence.

Basically what I do is I am working in web development for 2 years and I have:

- done few projects in pair programming
- done few average size tasks (e.g. CRUD module part of larger app)
- implement features in web site.

I haven't say done one big web site on my own.

Now the way I described all my experience **in one sentence is** say on Linkedin:

- *Participate* in the development of internal web applications (front end); technology: x,y,z.

My question is does using the word **participate** sound bad?

I know I could make it more elaborate but assume I want to describe it in one sentence. Is this fine or I am overthinking?

---

PS. if in the future I do more larger sites alone then I could change text to:

"Development of web applications...." etc.

Comment: Why limit yourself to one sentence?

Comment: @David K Sorry I forgot to register can't reply to your comment. Just for time being assume I prefer it to be one sentence I am not applying anywhere etc. Just want to put that on linkedin. ps. later if I apply I may break it down unless it will be too many bullet points then I will have to unite them somehow anyway. pps. feel free to delete this once it is read.

Comment: @david I've moved your answer to a comment. Please consult [this page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Simply dropping "participate" (so saying "Development of web applications...") would be better.

Much of what is done in the working world is done in teams, so people will generally assume you didn't do any given task all by yourself (unless you specifically say you did).

Answer (score -2):

No.

Just pretend you did all the work when you write your resume, and then phrase it that way. That just sounds better. When people ask you about it, then you can explain what you did more specifically.

Comment: "No" what? No, it doesn't sound bad to say "participate"? No, the OP isn't overthinking it? Or No, don't phrase it that way?

Comment: @DavidK what? from context i literally tell the OP to write their resume with the view that they did all the work. The No, then, refers to using the word "participate"

Comment: With a reputation like yours, you are recommending lying??!!

Comment: @Mawg what? ugh. no this is how you present your work. it reads better and is clearer. my last sentence is there to explain that when asked op clarify what op did

Comment: OIC; then perhaps rephrase - "just imagine to yourself that you wrote it all, then ...". You are attracting downvotes because it looks at first glance like you are advocating lying